# How to get the computer's current volume level?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How do I access the current volume level of a Mac from the Cocoa API?

For example: when I'm using Spotify.app on OS X 10.7 and a sound advertisement comes up, and I turn down my Mac's volume, the app will pause the ad until I turn it back up to an average level. I find this incredibly obnoxious and a violation of user privacy, but somehow Spotify has found a way to do this.

Is there any way I can do this with Cocoa? I'm making an app where it might come in useful to warn the user if the volume is low.

Comment: There isn't a single “current volume level”. There is one for each device, often one *per channel* on a device, and there are two meta-devices (at least for output): the “default output device” (for most sound output) and the “alert output device” (for alert sounds, interface sounds, etc.).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two options available.  The first step is to determine what device you'd like and get its ID.  Assuming the default output device, the code will look something like:

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = { 
    kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice, 
    kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal, 
    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster 
};

AudioDeviceID deviceID;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(deviceID);
OSStatus result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &deviceID);

if(kAudioHardwareNoError != result)
    // Handle the error
```

Next, you can use the [`kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/kaudiohardwareservicedeviceproperty_virtualmastervolume) property to get the device's virtual master volume:

```
AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = { 
    kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume, 
    kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
    kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster 
};

if(!AudioHardwareServiceHasProperty(deviceID, &propertyAddress))
    // An error occurred

Float32 volume;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(volume);
OSStatus result = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(deviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &volume);

if(kAudioHardwareNoError != result)
    // An error occurred
```

Alternatively, you can use `kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar` to get the volume for a specific channel:

```
UInt32 channel = 1; // Channel 0  is master, if available
AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAddress = { 
    kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar, 
    kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
    channel 
};

if(!AudioObjectHasProperty(deviceID, &propertyAddress))
    // An error occurred

Float32 volume;
UInt32 dataSize = sizeof(volume);
OSStatus result = AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceID, &propertyAddress, 0, NULL, &dataSize, &volume);

if(kAudioHardwareNoError != result)
    // An error occurred
```

The difference between the two is explained in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/kaudiohardwareservicedeviceproperty_virtualmastervolume#discussion):

> kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume
>
> A Float32 value that represents the value of the volume control. The
>   range for this property’s value is 0.0 (silence) through 1.0 (full
>   level). The effect of this property depends on the hardware device
>   associated with the HAL audio object. If the device has a master
>   volume control, this property controls it. If the device has
>   individual channel volume controls, this property applies to those
>   identified by the device's preferred multichannel layout, or the
>   preferred stereo pair if the device is stereo only. This control
>   maintains relative balance between the channels it affects.

So it can be tricky to define exactly what a device's volume is, especially for multichannel devices with non-standard channel maps.

Comment: Where does `kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume` come in in that code?

Comment: I didn't post code for this originally because Isaac seemed to cover that in his answer. I'll add it to my answer to make it more complete, however.

Comment: I'm getting a kAudioHardwareUnknownPropertyError for AudioObjectGetPropertyData using both kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume and kAudioDevicePropertyVolumeScalar. Xcode 7.3.1 OS X 10.10

Answer (score 2):

From [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/SoundVolume), these class methods look like they should work, though it's not particularly Cocoa-like:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

+(AudioDeviceID)defaultOutputDeviceID
{
    AudioDeviceID   outputDeviceID = kAudioObjectUnknown;

    // get output device device
    UInt32 propertySize = 0;
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAOPA;
    propertyAOPA.mScope = kAudioObjectPropertyScopeGlobal;
    propertyAOPA.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
    propertyAOPA.mSelector = kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice;

    if (!AudioHardwareServiceHasProperty(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAOPA))
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot find default output device!");
        return outputDeviceID;
    }

    propertySize = sizeof(AudioDeviceID);

    status = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(kAudioObjectSystemObject, &propertyAOPA, 0, NULL, &propertySize, &outputDeviceID);

    if(status) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot find default output device!");
    }
    return outputDeviceID;
}

// getting system volume

+(float)volume 
{
    Float32         outputVolume;

    UInt32 propertySize = 0;
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    AudioObjectPropertyAddress propertyAOPA;
    propertyAOPA.mElement = kAudioObjectPropertyElementMaster;
    propertyAOPA.mSelector = kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMasterVolume;
    propertyAOPA.mScope = kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput;

    AudioDeviceID outputDeviceID = [[self class] defaultOutputDeviceID];

    if (outputDeviceID == kAudioObjectUnknown)
    {
        NSLog(@"Unknown device");
        return 0.0;
    }

    if (!AudioHardwareServiceHasProperty(outputDeviceID, &propertyAOPA))
    {
        NSLog(@"No volume returned for device 0x%0x", outputDeviceID);
        return 0.0;
    }

    propertySize = sizeof(Float32);

    status = AudioHardwareServiceGetPropertyData(outputDeviceID, &propertyAOPA, 0, NULL, &propertySize, &outputVolume);

    if (status)
    {
        NSLog(@"No volume returned for device 0x%0x", outputDeviceID);
        return 0.0;
    }

    if (outputVolume < 0.0 || outputVolume > 1.0) return 0.0;

    return outputVolume;
}
```

Comment: @sbooth: copy/paste fail on my part.  Should be fixed now.  (And +1 on your answer, which seems to be along the same lines, but actually explains it.)

Comment: Link to CocoaDev is dead. This requires `-framework Cocoa -framework AudioToolbox`

Comment: @AlecJacobson The link should be fixed now.